# Compressible Ebin-Marsden?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, fluid-dynamics

In Ebin and Marsden's paper [Groups of Diffeomorphisms and the Motion of an Incompressible Fluid](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970699?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), there is a footnote on the first page indicating that non-homogeneous cases and the case of *compressible* fluid mechanics will be treated in a forthcoming paper.

Having taken a search through MathSciNet I did not see anything obvious as the mentioned followup. Does anyone have a reference as to which paper that is referring to?

Answer (score 7):

I have worked for decades on compressible gas dynamics, and I am not aware of such a followup by Ebin & Marsden. But I think you will find something in the book of Arnol'd & Khesin.

Comment: (Just for my later reference: this is _Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics_.)

Answer (score 6):

The compressible case uses semidirect products of groups (group of diffeomorphisms times functions).
To my knowledge, the first paper that discusses this in detail is
[Marsden, Ratiu, Weinstein: Semidirect Products and Reduction in Mechanics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1999527) [(PDF)](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emarsden/bib/1984/01-MaRaWe1984/MaRaWe1984.pdf).
There the authors state

> By 1980 it was known that the equations for compressible flow on R3 were
> formally Lie-Poisson equations for the semidirect product...

So even back then it was already folklore.